# Is there a way to recommend (share) a show to your friends from an Xbox app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, xbox-one

I am developing an UWP app for xbox one. Is it possible to share a link from my app to my friends (Facebook, Twitter...etc)?

Comment: It depends entirely on where you publish your application to. That's a question that storefront or server, not here.

Comment: All the UWP app's get published to the Windows store.

Answer (score 0):

Just take Facebook as an example, if you want to share a link from your app to Facebook, you can try to use the Facebook api. This [Windows SDK for Facebook](http://microsoft.github.io/winsdkfb/#feed_dialog) teaches you how to start and you can use `FBSession.ShowFeedDialogAsync()` method to share the link. About the specific steps, you can refer to this [document](http://microsoft.github.io/winsdkfb/sample/).